# Authentication issue in 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Negotiate, NTLM'

Tags: python, linux, authentication, kerberos, ntlm

I am working on a red-hat vncsession, I want to extract data from a webpage which has XML content from command line when I use python it gives the message access denied. I can open the URL in firefox it pops up a window and asks for credentials.I have used the "python ntlm module kerbose module" and also curl and wget with ntlm option but no luck. 
when I use 
r=requests,get('http//.....')
r.headers
output has

'WWW-Authenticate': 'Negotiate, NTLM',  'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5'

fields.

Please help

Comment: What is your question actually?